# A more formal way to say "il m'a posé un lapin"?

Tags: expressions, registre

Up until now the only way I know to describe someone cancelling plans in the last second - the English term being "stood me up" - is "il m'a posé un lapin".

That sounds a little too informal (I imagine). Is there a more formal way to describe such a situation?

Comment: I would point out that "poser un lapin" usually suggests a plain-and-simple (and certainly rude) no-show, rather than plans canceled at the last minute.

Comment: s/unformal/informal/   please.  The edit system would not let me do that as 2 characters is two few.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comme l'a justement fait remarquer [Patrice M.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17685/a-more-formal-way-to-say-il-ma-pos%C3%A9-un-lapin#comment33331_17685), il me semble que « poser un lapin » implique à la fois une **annulation de dernière minute** qui rend l'action fort discourtoise, et le **choix délibéré** d'une telle annulation, que ne reflète pas du tout l'expression « ne pas se présenter au rendez-vous ». Ainsi, dans aucune des situations suivantes, je ne pense « poser de lapin » :

- J'annule expressément un rendez-vous bien à l'avance.
- Je ne peux pas arriver à temps au rendez-vous parce que je suis coincé dans les embouteillages.

Si ni le [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/lapin/46241/locution), ni le [Dictionnaire de l'Académie française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/lapin) ne font mention de cette nuance, tous les deux s'accordent effectivement à qualifier l'expression de **populaire**.

En revanche, selon moi, l'expression « faire faux bond » ([Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bond/10122/locution), [Dictionnaire de l'Académie française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/bond)) a exactement le même sens, tout en étant d'un niveau de langue courant.

Comment: Très bonne réponse à mon avis. J'avais aussi noté que _Larousse_ marque familier pour _se défiler_ ; ça m'a un peu surpris.

Answer (score 6):

It's informal yes. More formal, you can say "Il n'est pas venu au rendez-vous"

Answer (score 3):

HiroCortes> be careful: that's in the past, so it will be

"Il ne s'est pas présenté à notre rendez-vous (de mercredi)."

Comment: Très bonne remarque, mais cela devrait être un commentaire sur la réponse d'HiroCores, et non une réponse en elle-même :) .

Answer (score 2):

If your focus is formality then:"Il ne se présente pas pour notre rendez-vous" works too :)